# Postgresql with Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Im trying to use Postgresql with Play for their Yabe tutorial and get this error:

Cannot connected to the database, Driver not found (org.postgresql.Driver)

Here is my connection string:

```
# If you need a full JDBC configuration use the following :
 db.url=jdbc:postgresql:yabe
 db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver  
 db.user=yabe
 db.pass=yabe
#
# Connections pool configuration :
 db.pool.timeout=1000
 db.pool.maxSize=30
 db.pool.minSize=1
```

In my lib folder I have this:
postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc3.jar

I tried changing the driver name to the same name is tha jar but still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that the org.postgresql.Driver is in the Jar?

Comment: Hi Niels. I didn't. I downloaded the driver from Postgresql. Ill check what you suggested.

Comment: I added a dependency for this in the .yml file and it successfully downloads the .jar file. I still get this error though. A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, Driver not found (postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar)

Comment: Please check it directly by looking into the jar.

Comment: heres whats in the jar.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.0-801.jdbc4/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Play framework already includes the driver for Postgres. do the following:

- Remove any reference to postgreSQL drivers from your dependencies.yml files
- Do a "play deps --sync"
- Remove any jar in your lib/ folder related to postgreSQL drivers
- Change your connection string to:

  db=postgres://user:pwd@localhost:5432/yabe

This should solve the conflict you have.

Comment: None of this is true for Play 2

Comment: @MikeSlinn yes, well, this was a Play 1 question :)

Answer (score 40):

If you are using Play 2.0 this works slightly differently.  The url actually looks like this:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://user:password@servername/dataBaseName"
```

But this will also error out unless you add the following lines to you dependencies section in build.scala or build.java:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
```

Answer (score 13):

If you need SSL support:

```
db=postgres://user:password@server.example.net:5432/dbname?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to edit a full JDBC configuration. I use postgesql in local and I just add this line in application.conf file in conf folder :

```
# To connect to a local PostgreSQL9 database, use:
db=postgres://userName:yourPassword@localhost:5432/nameOfYourDB
```

If you are in local, userName is often postgres unless you changed it.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and this is the error i receive:

A JPA error occurred (Cannot start a JPA manager without a properly configured database): No datasource configured

Answer (score 3):

You should copy PostgresSql driver version "JDBC 4" [What you have is JDBC 3]. Get it from [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)

Alternatively you may use `- postgresql 9.1-901.jdbc4` in your dependencies. But I think Maven doesn't have this latest version yet.

Comment: Copy? Doesn't the dependency pull it down?

Comment: Dependency will pull it down if the jar is available in Maven central. But as I said, this latest version is not available yet. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql

Comment: It doesnt matter what version i pull down. I get an error.

Here is what i have setup:


application.conf
db.url=jdbc:postgresql:yabe 
db.driver=postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar
db.user=yabe
db.pass=password

dependancies.yml
require:
    - play
    - postgresql -> postgresql 9.0-801.jdbc4


The error:
A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, Driver not found (postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"